# Why wont my code work? seems to be an error with my list in my child class but cant work out what?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

**Here is my Code:
I can,t change anything as the task is set but I just can't find my error? all and any help is appreciated!**

I understand the bulk of the code and it's a great book that's really helped my programming and I thought the inheritance was very easy but I just can't find the error in this code it seems to be on the list (which is required for the task) but I can't find what the problem is.

```
#defines a class called Restaurant.
class Restaurant():

    #defines the instances to be used in the class.
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0


    #defines the instance to show the cuisine.
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("\nThe Restaurant {0} sells {1} food.".format(self.restaurant_name.capitalize(), self.cuisine_type.capitalize()))


    #this sets the number of customers served.
    def set_number_served(self, customers):
        self.number_served = customers


    #this sets the increment for customers.
    def increment_number_served(self, people):
        self.number_served +=people


    #defines the instance to show the Restaurant is open.
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print("The Restaurant {0} is Open.".format(self.restaurant_name.capitalize()))


    #defines the instance to show the number of customers served.
    def restaurant(self):
        print("The Restaurant has served {0} people.\n".format(str(self.number_served).capitalize()))


class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type="ice_cream"):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavours = []

    def show_flavours(self):
        print("\nWe have the following flavours available:")
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print("--", flavour())

#makes the class ready to call.
res = Restaurant("McDonald's", "Fast")

rest = Restaurant("Prezzo's", "Italian")

resta = Restaurant("The Wok Place", "Chinese")

#calls the instances from the class.
res.describe_restaurant()
res.open_restaurant()
res.set_number_served(10000)
res.increment_number_served(300)
res.restaurant()

rest.describe_restaurant()
rest.open_restaurant()
rest.set_number_served(3000)
rest.increment_number_served(500)
rest.restaurant()

resta.describe_restaurant()
resta.open_restaurant()
resta.set_number_served(500)
resta.increment_number_served(100)
resta.restaurant()

bobs_ice = ("Bobs Ice")
bobs_ice.flavours = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Pistachio", "Caramel"]

bobs_ice.describe_restaurant()
bobs_ice.show_flavours()
```

**I keep getting this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CJH-DESKTOP\Desktop\Python Activities\restaurant with classes.py", line 75, in <module>
    bobs_ice.flavours = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Pistachio", "Caramel"]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'flavours'
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
bobs_ice = ("Bobs Ice")
```

should probably be

```
bobs_ice = IceCreamStand("Bobs Ice")
```

As it is right now, bobs_ice is a string, and you can't assign new attributes to strings.

Comment: seem to now be getting this error:  
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 78, in <module> bobs_ice.show_flavours() File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 46, in show_flavours print("--", flavour()) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

```
bobs_ice = ("Bobs Ice")
```

is just saying that `bobs_ice` is a string. Obviously, `str.flavours` isn't a thing, so you are getting an error.
You probably mean:

```
bobs_ice = IceCreamStand("Bobs Ice")
```

Comment: done that but i now appear to be getting the following error?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 78, in <module>
    bobs_ice.show_flavours()
  File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 46, in show_flavours
    print("--", flavour())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Change `print("---", flavour())` to `print("---", flavour)`. A string is not a function and cannot be called as one.

Answer (score 0):

You did not instantiate `bobs_ice` as an instance of `IceCreamStand`:

You are also calling  a string here `print("--", flavour())`; do this instead: `print("--", flavour)`

```
#defines a class called Restaurant.
class Restaurant():

    #defines the instances to be used in the class.
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0


    #defines the instance to show the cuisine.
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("\nThe Restaurant {0} sells {1} food.".format(self.restaurant_name.capitalize(), self.cuisine_type.capitalize()))


    #this sets the number of customers served.
    def set_number_served(self, customers):
        self.number_served = customers


    #this sets the increment for customers.
    def increment_number_served(self, people):
        self.number_served +=people


    #defines the instance to show the Restaurant is open.
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print("The Restaurant {0} is Open.".format(self.restaurant_name.capitalize()))


    #defines the instance to show the number of customers served.
    def restaurant(self):
        print("The Restaurant has served {0} people.\n".format(str(self.number_served).capitalize()))


class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type="ice_cream"):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavours = []

    def show_flavours(self):
        print("\nWe have the following flavours available:")
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print("--", flavour)     # <<== THERE, don't call a string

#makes the class ready to call.
res = Restaurant("McDonald's", "Fast")

rest = Restaurant("Prezzo's", "Italian")

resta = Restaurant("The Wok Place", "Chinese")

#calls the instances from the class.
res.describe_restaurant()
res.open_restaurant()
res.set_number_served(10000)
res.increment_number_served(300)
res.restaurant()

rest.describe_restaurant()
rest.open_restaurant()
rest.set_number_served(3000)
rest.increment_number_served(500)
rest.restaurant()

resta.describe_restaurant()
resta.open_restaurant()
resta.set_number_served(500)
resta.increment_number_served(100)
resta.restaurant()

bobs_ice = IceCreamStand("Bobs Ice")    #<<=== HERE!
bobs_ice.flavours = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Pistachio", "Caramel"]

bobs_ice.describe_restaurant()  
bobs_ice.show_flavours()
```

Comment: seem to now be getting this error:  
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 78, in <module> bobs_ice.show_flavours() File "C:/Users/CJH-DESKTOP/Desktop/Python Activities/restaurant with classes.py", line 46, in show_flavours print("--", flavour()) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: It is `print("--", flavour)` not `print("--", flavour())`, just as I posted in my answer! All you have to do is copy paste the code in your IDE, and run it.